# What is soft real-time system?

Tags: workflow, real-time

Realitme system must process request in reasonable time. But for what standing soft?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Criteria_for_real-time_computing

Comment: thanks, why not answer, but comment?

Comment: Who downvotes, please, write why. Or i must be afraid to ask questions at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very simple, it takes couple seconds to find the answer in Google.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Criteria_for_real-time_computing